# Card shuffling dealing program

Tags: c

I'm getting the following errors when I compile my C program. I'm just a beginner so I appreciate any help here

```
main.c: In function ‘print_card’:
main.c:53:12: error: ‘face’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     printf(face[n % 13] + " of " + suit[n / 13]);
            ^~~~
main.c:53:12: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
main.c:53:36: error: ‘suit’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     printf(face[n % 13] + " of " + suit[n / 13]);
                                    ^~~~
```

I need to output something similar to this:
king of Diamonds
Nine of Clubs

**Any suggestions (I'm a beginner) I may have done something wrong. Here is my code**

```
/* Card shuffling dealing program */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

/* prototypes */


void shuffleAndDeal( int workdeck[][ 13 ], const char *workface[],const char *worksuit[] );
void print_card(int n);

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
/* initialize suit array */
 const char *suit[ 4 ] = { "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades" };

 /* initialize face array */
 const char *face[ 13 ] =
 { "Ace", "Deuce", "Three", "Four",
 "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight",
 "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };
 /* initialize deck array */
 int deck[ 4 ][ 13 ] = { 0 };
 
 srand( time( 0 ) ); /* seed random-number generator */
 shuffleAndDeal( deck, face, suit );
 return 0; /* indicates successful termination */
} 


void shuffleAndDeal( int workdeck[][ 13 ], const char *workface[], const char *worksuit[] ) {
//  srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    int deck[52];

    // Prime, shuffle, dump
    for (int i=0;i<52;deck[i++]=i);
    random_shuffle(deck, deck+52);
    for_each(deck, deck+52, print_card);
    return;
}

void print_card(int n) {
    printf(face[n % 13] + " of " + suit[n / 13]);
}
```

Comment: `face` is local to `main` and is not visible in other functions.

Comment: You don't use `+` in C for string concatenation. Where did you learn that? The first argument to `printf()` should be a format string.

Comment: `printf("%s of %s\n", face[n%13], suit[n/13]);`

Comment: You could make `face` and `suit` global variables.

Comment: Where do you define `for_each`?

Comment: `shuffleAndDeal` never uses any of the parameters, what are they for?

Comment: @Ba I think I'm lost, so what's the correct way to rewrite my printf() please

Answer (score 1):

You should declare `suit` and `face` as global variables so that they can be referenced in multiple functions.

Don't use `deck[i++] = i`. This causes undefined behavior because you're incrementing `i` and reading from it in the same expression, without a sequence point. Put the assignment inside the loop body.

`printf()` uses a format string to specify where to fill in the values of other arguments. You can't concatenate strings with `+` there.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* initialize suit array */
const char *suit[ 4 ] = { "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades" };
/* initialize face array */
const char *face[ 13 ] = { "Ace", "Deuce", "Three", "Four",
                           "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight",
                           "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };

void for_each(int *start, int *end, void(*f)(int)) {
    for (int *cur = start; cur < end; cur++) {
        f(*cur);
    }
}

void print_card(int n) {
    printf("%s of %s\n", face[n % 13], suit[n / 13]);
}

void shuffleAndDeal( int workdeck[][ 13 ], const char *workface[], const char *worksuit[] ) {
//  srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    int deck[52];

    // Prime, shuffle, dump
    for (int i=0;i<52;i++) {
        deck[i] = i;
    }
    random_shuffle(deck, deck+52);
    for_each(deck, deck+52, print_card);
    return;
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
/* initialize deck array */
    int deck[ 4 ][ 13 ] = { 0 };
    shuffleAndDeal( deck, face, suit );
    return 0; /* indicates successful termination */
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you. I'm getting the following error now: In function `shuffleAndDeal':
main.c:(.text+0x124): undefined reference to `random_shuffle'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: You need to define that function, of course. I added `for_each()` because it's simple.